# Is there a way to preload selected options on multiple chosen.js select boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-chosen

I have 10 forms with 5 chosen.js select boxes in each form group. When the page loads I want to load the chosen select boxes with options which have set on another select box, which is hidden from view.

The idea is that the user can deselect the options they don't want, and update the form.

There's a challenge in assigning the correct options to the correct chosen select but what I'm trying to do now is get the already selected options to show.

An example of what it would look like is near the top of the [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) page. It appears when the page loads 'Sloth Bear' and 'Polar Bear' are already pre-populating their select box.
[image]
I've tried chosen:update but my understanding is that it only updates the possible options you can select, not what I'm wanting. I've also tried manually inserting a DOM node into the chosen input, but that wasn't working either.

So is what I'm trying possible? Or is it just an example on the website?

Comment: It is easier to help you if you post a [mcve] using a `[<>]` stack snippet. You likely need `$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");`

Comment: Iwould look at https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues and add one if you do not find it - for example https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2731

Comment: OK thanks, I'll take a look . I wasn't sure how to format an example given the library would change the markup of the select box into a input or whatever it uses, hence the photo.